# Create CSV file using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have `dataTable`, I want to create a new list with some extra field, using `Parallel.ForEach.`

example :

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable().AsEnumerable(), drow =>
{

Create new list

});
```

Comment: Why Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: Is it okay the new collection to be Concurrent collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` is *not thread-safe*, that's why `Parallel.ForEach` is not easy to marry `List<T>`. Try using *Linq* and its parallel version *PLinq*, let .Net doe the work for you; something like this:

```
 var list = dt
  .AsEnumerable() 
  .AsParallel()
  .AsOrdered() // if you want to preserve rows order
  .Select(drow => string.Join(",", drow[1], drow[5], drow[11], ExtraData(drow[5])))
  .ToList();
```

If you want to save the `list` as a *file* use `File` class:

```
 using System.IO;

 ...

 string fileName = @"C:\MyFile.csv";

 File.WriteAllLines(fileName, list);
```

In the toy example above I've assumed that we want to have CSV based on 2nd, 4th and 12th columns enriched by `ExtraData(drow[5])` and all the columns' values don't contain `"` and `,` characters

Comment: Hi, It's working perfectly, However, can I know How I will convert to CSV, I am very new to C#.

Comment: @Gouri Mahapatra: do you mean, how can you write the list as a CSV *file*?

Comment: yes, List already having comma separated record, I want to convert into this list to csv file. Thanks

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.csv", list);` saves the collection as a file

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks u for ur support

Comment: Hi,I have one more question: How I can add this list to a Dictionary object, having Key and a list.  Some thing like this var list = dt
              .AsEnumerable()
              .AsParallel()
              .AsOrdered()
              .Select(drow => testList.Add(drow[0].ToString(), new List{ drow[0].ToString() }))

              .ToList();  can u guide me